# How to get screen DPI (PPI) in Android NDK using C++ class?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

In Java, I know I can use DisplayMetrics to get DPI i.e. PPI i.e. pixels per inch.
However NDK/C++ do not seem to have this class. 
How then can I get PPI in an Android C++ app?
Failing that how can I get screen dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) {
JNIEnv *env = NULL;
if (vm->GetEnv((void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK) {
    return JNI_ERR;
}
// getting instance of application
jobject application = NULL;
jclass activity_thread_clz = env->FindClass("android/app/ActivityThread");
if (activity_thread_clz != NULL) {
    jmethodID currentApplication = env->GetStaticMethodID(
            activity_thread_clz, "currentApplication", "()Landroid/app/Application;");
    if (currentApplication != NULL) {
        application = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(activity_thread_clz, currentApplication);
    } else {
        Logger::Error("Helper::getApplication","Cannot find method: currentApplication() in ActivityThread.");
    }
    env->DeleteLocalRef(activity_thread_clz);
} else {
    Logger::Error("Helper::getApplication","Cannot find class: android.app.ActivityThread.");
}

// getting WindowManager Service
jmethodID getWindowManager = env->GetMethodID (context, "getSystemService" , "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
jstring serviceName = env->NewStringUTF("window");
jobject wm = env->CallObjectMethod(application, getWindowManager,serviceName);
jclass windowManagerClass = env->FindClass("android/view/WindowManager");

// getting default display
jmethodID getDefaultDisplay = env->GetMethodID(windowManagerClass, "getDefaultDisplay" , "()Landroid/view/Display;");
jobject display = env->CallObjectMethod(wm, getDefaultDisplay);
jclass displayClass = env->FindClass("android/view/Display");

// getting Display metrics
jclass displayMetricsClass = env->FindClass("android/util/DisplayMetrics");
jmethodID displayMetricsConstructor = env->GetMethodID(displayMetricsClass, "<init>", "()V");
jobject displayMetrics = env->NewObject(displayMetricsClass, displayMetricsConstructor);
jmethodID getMetrics = env->GetMethodID(displayClass, "getMetrics", "(Landroid/util/DisplayMetrics;)V");
env->CallVoidMethod(display, getMetrics, displayMetrics);
jfieldID xdpi_id = env->GetFieldID(displayMetricsClass, "xdpi", "F");
float xdpi = env->GetFloatField( displayMetrics, xdpi_id);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).